# Hibernate criteria to have multiple restrictions on the child collection

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have to write a criteria query with where clause to match both first & last names in the child collection. Both names are in different rows

Tried this, but does not return anything even when the matching data is present, probably because it's trying to match both restrictions on same row.

```
Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Form.class);
criteria.createAlias("responses", "r");
criteria.add(Restrictions
                .conjunction()
                .add(Restrictions.eq("r.id", "firstName"))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("r.value", getFirstName())));
criteria.add(Restrictions
                .conjunction()
                .add(Restrictions.eq("r.id", "lastName"))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("r.value", getLastName())));
```

Tried this and this gives an exception *org.hibernate.QueryException: duplicate association path: responses*

```
Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Form.class);
criteria.createAlias("responses", "r1");
criteria.createAlias("responses", "r2");

criteria.add(Restrictions
                .conjunction()
                .add(Restrictions.eq("r1.id", "firstName"))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("r1.value", getFirstName())));
criteria.add(Restrictions
                .conjunction()
                .add(Restrictions.eq("r2.id", "lastName"))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("r2.value", getLastName())));
```

Any help?

**EDIT**

It looks like from the description the question wasn't clear. Here is the basic requirement:

*Query all records from form class which have  (A child response record with id=firstName AND value=someName1) AND (A child response record with id=lastName AND value=someName2)*

I am also adding the solution which worked for me, using the subqueries. Not sure if this was the best way, but it solved my problem

Comment: so if I understand you problem : you want to query with a OR instead of AND ?

Comment: @jpprade I actually wanted an AND

Comment: @NarainMittal, I think confusion is in your understanding. When you need to fire a query having restrictions on two different rows, you have to use OR instead of AND. When you say AND, both the restrictions will be applied to same row. So What jpprade has suggested you is the correct solution.

Comment: @RAS Apologies for not being able to respond sooner, but please check the edit. I did need an AND. Also see the answer which worked for me

Comment: @NarainMittal, great. Accept the answer that worked for you so that future visitors can be guided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem using subqueries instead. Looks like hibernate doesn't support multiple joins on the same child record.

```
Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Form.class);             
DetachedCriteria subQuery1 = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Response.class);
subQuery1.add(Restrictions.and(
    Restrictions.eq("id", "firstName").add(
    Restrictions.eq("value", getFirstName())));
subQuery1.setProjection(Projections.property("formId"));

DetachedCriteria subQuery2 = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Response.class);
subQuery2.add(Restrictions.and(
    Restrictions.eq("id", "lastName").add(
    Restrictions.eq("value", getLastName())));
subQuery2.setProjection(Projections.property("formId"));
criteria.add(Restrictions.and(Subqueries.propertyIn("id", subQuery1),
                Subqueries.propertyIn("id", subQuery2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

To query with a OR :

```
Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Form.class);
criteria.createAlias("responses", "r");
Junction conditionGroup = Restrictions.disjunction();
conditionGroup.add(Restrictions
                .conjunction()
                .add(Restrictions.eq("r.id", "firstName"))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("r.value", getFirstName())));
conditionGroup.add(Restrictions
                .conjunction()
                .add(Restrictions.eq("r.id", "lastName"))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("r.value", getLastName())));
criteria.add(conditionGroup);
```